# Are Selendroid Tests supported by any of the cloud based Test Labs?

Tags: android, automation, selendroid

Our Objective is to run our Selendroid tests on multiple virtual devices of different configurations and resolutions simultaneously. We are using Selendroid with testNG to test our android app. As I was researching about the cloud test labs, Amazon web services, Sauce labs and Xamarin test cloud and TestObject Device, I didn't find any documentation regarding Test Labs supporting selendroid tests.
So, does any of the above support Selendroid tests?
If Yes, may I get some Links of info to start with the set up.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Sauce Labs uses Selendroid.  Their [configuration page](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Platform+Configurator#/) lets you choice devices based on Selenium, Appium, or Selendroid.

I also know from experience that they will use a Selendroid server when running tests against an Android, even if you use the Appium configuration for specifying an android.